# "Packing" linux up onto USB drive

Tags: linux, linux-mint, live-usb

I have been using my Linux Mint Nadia for some time and customized it a little, I was wondering if I can "pack it" onto a USB and make it into an ISO which I can boot on another computer and it will have all the settings and files that I currently have? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but I'm not sure how automated an approach it's going to be. You can see this example using Arch Linux where they take a previously installed Arch Linux system and create similar partitions on a USB thumb drive and then use rsync to copy the files over to their corresponding locations on the thumb drive.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=139680

To accomplish this you'll need to make sure of tools such as `gparted` & `rsync` and have to have familiarity in editing your grub menu on the USB thumb drive to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with mint using remastersys.  It seems a new developer is taking over the project.  The new URL is http://system-imaging.blogspot.ca

Answer (score -1):

First do this:
http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/

Then do this:
http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [questions and answers site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/about), not a link farm. Please do not post an answer that just contains links. Your answer must make sense even if the reader cannot or does not follow the links. For more tips on writing good answers, read [how to answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer).